# How do I store key-value pairs in a column and query those values with comparisons

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am not sure if this is the best way to go about the problem I am facing.

I have a table of game items, where each game item has up to 13 types of upgradable items.

Each upgradeable item is denoted by a single character (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C).

So let's say the item has 3 of upgradeable item "B", and "7" of upgradeable item "C", what's the best way to store this information under a single column and be able to pull out what upgradeable items exist for that item, and select items that have greater than or equal to "x" number of a specific upgradeable item.

It looks easy to solve isn't it? A foreign table for the upgradeable items and we plug the upgradeables there and boom, but no, sadly not, it needs to be in the same column, cannot add any more columns or tables.

Comment: "cannot add any more columns or tables" -- why? It seems a little pointless to ask a database design question but saying that you cannot alter the design of the database...

Comment: @stickybit client rules

Comment: Then tell them, that this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @stickybit wish saying "NO" was an option. :/

Comment: Add another room to my house but don't do any building... won't work.

Comment: @stickybit ikr I figured out half of the problem and the only missing piece of the puzzle is how to use a greater than condition on it. Not a practical solution, but opens your mind to learning new things

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Can you please post the DDL to generate your existing table or at least a visual of what the columns are? (Your question could use a little more context too, like what you've tried and where you're currently stuck.)

Comment: The definition of "upgradable" is too vague; please elaborate.  We may need to use an algorithm to perform the "upgrade" or may need to use 'table lookup' to determine the upgrade.  Also, what are the rules for when an upgrade can (or does) happen; this may lead to an `UPDATE` statement or something else.